# How is the .similarity method in SpaCy computed?

Tags: natural-language, word2vec, tf-idf, nltk

Not Sure if this is the right stack site, but here goes.

## How does the .similiarity method work?

Wow spaCy is great! Its tfidf model could be easier, but w2v with only one line of code?!

In his  [10 line tutorial on spaCy](https://github.com/cytora/pycon-nlp-in-10-lines/blob/master/00_spacy_intro.ipynb) andrazhribernik show's us the .similarity method that can be run on tokens, sents, word chunks, and docs.

After `nlp = spacy.load('en')` and `doc = nlp(raw_text)`
we can do .similarity queries between tokens and chunks.
However, what is being calculated behind the scenes in this `.similarity` method?

SpaCy already has the incredibly simple `.vector`, which computes the w2v vector as trained from the GloVe model (how cool would a `.tfidf` or `.fasttext` method be?).

Is the model simply computing the cosine similarity between these two w2v, .vector, vectors or comparing some other matrix? The specifics aren't clear in the [documentation](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/word-vectors-similarities); any help appreciated!

Comment: "how cool would a .tfidf or .fasttext method be?"  the [docs](https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity#custom-loading-other) provide an example of replacing the GloVe vectors with FastText.  It's maybe not exactly the same as having them together. [Github](https://github.com/explosion/spacy/blob/master/examples/vectors_fast_text.py)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Found the answer, in short, it's yes:

[Link to Source Code](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/word-vectors-similarities)

```
return numpy.dot(self.vector, other.vector) / (self.vector_norm * other.vector_norm)
```

This looks like it's the formula for computing [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity#Definition) and the vectors seem to be created with SpaCy's `.vector` which the documentation says is trained from GloVe's w2v model.

Answer (score 6):

By default it's cosine similarity, with vectors averaged over the document for missing words.

You can also customize this, by setting a hook to `doc.user_hooks['similarity']`. This pipeline component wraps similarity functions, making it easy to customise the similarity:

https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/develop/spacy/pipeline.pyx#L50

Comment: Tecnically, you appear to have linked to the `SentenceSegmenter` strategy.